# Finding remainder of a product divided by $8$ with modular arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I was requested to find the remainder of $9^{52}*7^{33}$ when dividing it by $8$, using modular arithmetic. Let that remainder be $r$. I understand the following will apply:

$9^{52}*7^{33} \equiv r \mod{(8)}$

so that all I must find is the congruence of the product in the module $8$. But how can one go about solving this? I don't have any tries worth showing, since I simply ignore what procedure could be followed.

Comment: $7\equiv -1$ and $9\equiv 1$ mod $8$, so the expression is equal to $$1^{52}\cdot(-1)^{33}\bmod8=-1$$

Comment: But doesn't this mean the remainder of the division is negative? That does not make sense. What am I missing?

Comment: $-1\equiv 7\bmod8$.

Comment: Of course, how silly of me. Thank you very much for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Since $9$ is $1$ modulo $8$, so is any power. What can you say about odd powers of $7$ using the same kind of reasoning? To find a modulus after multiplying you multiply the two moduli.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$9\equiv 1,\qquad 7 \equiv -1\mod 8.$

Comment: Doesn't all this imply that $r = -1$? Since I'm left with $-1 \equiv r \mod (8)$. How can a remainder be negative?

Comment: There exists versions of Euclidean division  for which the remainder can be negative… This being  said, it is only a hint. You still have  to find the least positive integer which is congruent to $-1\bmod 8$. This shouldn't be too hard.